# How do I select a specific record from Many-to-many relationships which does not contain a specific item in Rails 2?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, model, many-to-many

I am stuck with this for a couple of hours. It could be a quick solution but my brain is overheated now. Ok here it is.

I have Session and SessionType models which have many-to-many relationships to each other as follows.

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :session_types
  ...
end

class SessionType < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sessions
  ...
end
```

What I want is to get a session which doesn't contain any specific session_type, eg.,

```
Session.find(:all, :joins => [:session_types], :conditions => ["session_types.id <> 44"])
```

It doesn't work for me since the above query will still give me the sessions which have session_types.id "44" in many of its associations because of the nature of many-to-many relationships.

Also the following mysql code doesn't work as well.

```
select sessions.* from sessions
INNER JOIN `session_types_sessions` ON `session_types_sessions`.session_id = `sessions`.id 
WHERE (  session_types_sessions.session_type_id NOT IN (44))
GROUP BY sessions.id
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First select those sessions which are of type 44:

```
session_types_44 = Session.find(:all, :joins => :session_types, 
  :conditions => { :"session_types.id" => 44 }).uniq
```

and select sessions which do not fall into the above:

```
sessions_without_type_44 = Session.find(:all, 
  :conditions => "id NOT IN (#{session_types_44.join(",")})")
```

You need to be careful with that because if `session_types_44` is empty array you will get SQL error.

And to answer your **second** question:

> do you know how I could change the SQL to filter like "get me sessions which have session_type_id '43', but they must NOT have '44'

Take the result from `sessions_without_type_44` and use it. First select SessionType with 43 and through association get all sessions which belong to that SessionType and their ids are within the `sessions_without_type_44`:

```
SessionType.find(43).sessions.all(:conditions => { 
  :id => sessions_without_type_44 })
```

Comment: Yes it works fine with a bit of syntax change as I have some syntax error around join. 
session_types_44 = Session.find(:all, :joins => :session_types, :conditions => { :"session_types.id" => 44 }).uniq
  
Session.find(:all, :conditions => ["id NOT IN (?)",session_types_44.collect { |s| s.id }])

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT sessions.*
FROM sessions
LEFT JOIN session_types_sessions ON session_types_sessions.session_id = sessions.id AND session_types_sessions.session_type_id = 44
WHERE session_types_sessions.session_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Great. Works in SQL. I need to find a way to integrate into Rails bit now.

Comment: How about `find_by_sql`? If you're using Rails 3 there should be an easy way to do this in AREL.

Comment: Ok I should be able to that. Just while you can help, do you know how I could change the SQL to filter like "get me sessions which have session_type_id '43', but they must NOT have '44'". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Session.all(
  :include => :session_types,
  :conditions => ["session_types.id IS NOT NULL AND session_types.id != ?", 44])
)
```

The `include` option uses LEFT JOIN hence this query will work.